# Sending the DEFAULT placeholder via JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there any way, via JDBC, to send the `DEFAULT` placeholder explicitly, like in `INSERT INTO sometables VALUES (blah, DEFAULT)`? (I'm almost certain the answer is "no", but I'm looking for JDBC-expert confirmation).

Say you had a `PreparedStatement` like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(a, b) VALUES (?, ?)
```

for table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    a integer,
    b integer default some_function()
);
```

and you wanted to use the database-set `DEFAULT` for `mytable.b` in some executions in a batch but not others.

In regular SQL you'd write:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(a, b) VALUES (1, 42)
INSERT INTO mytable(a, b) VALUES (2, DEFAULT);
...
```

or of course:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(a, b) VALUES (1, 42)
INSERT INTO mytable(a) VALUES (2);
```

... but you can't do this via JDBC. `setString("DEFAULT")` will of course not send the `DEFAULT` keyword, just the string-literal `'DEFAULT'`.

Is there a way to set a placeholder-parameter that means `DEFAULT` in any widely used drivers?

I don't see a way to do it with the standard API and spec.

I'm imagining something like:

```
pstmt.setObject(2, Postgresql.DEFAULT, Types.OTHER);
```

where `Postgresql.DEFAULT` is a special placeholder instance, since there doesn't seem to be a `setDefault()` method for [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Does any existing driver support this?

Comment: If you have few places where default value is required, you could just have two copies: `insert into mytable(a b) values (?, ?)` and `insert into mytable(a b) values (?, ?)`.

Comment: A workaround is to perform a prior query to get the column defaults, then include them as values in your PreparedStatement: SELECT `COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_DEFAULT` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dbName' AND `TABLE_NAME`='tableName';

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee That'll work if the defaults are literals, but may have surprising outcomes if the defaults are expressions - you can't include arbitrary SQL expressions as bind parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this. As far as I know the SQL standard does not support a mechanism for declaring to use the `DEFAULT` through parameters. The SQL standard seems to assume that each `INSERT` is crafted for its specific purpose. So declaring `DEFAULT` can only be done in the insert statement itself and not as a value for a parameter. In these kinds of decisions, the JDBC specification usually follows the SQL standard.

The only method you currently have is to create a vendor-specific method in the JDBC driver, for example as you specified in your question itself, but you could also think of something like:

**To clarify: below is an example of how a driver implementation could solve it, it doesn't actually work like this.**

Using [`setNull(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-)

```java
setNull(idx, PostgresTypes.DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

or using [`setNull(int, int, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-java.lang.String-)

```java
setNull(idx, Types.<correct-field-type>, Postgres.DEFAULT_VALUE_MARKER)
```

However this assumes that PostgreSQL actually has a method of specifying `DEFAULT` through parameters, or that the driver implementation will parse and recreate the statement for each set of received parameters so that it can declare a literal `DEFAULT`.

I don't know if there is any driver that currently supports such a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`default` isn't a value literal - it's a pseudocolumn (or at least I hope that's what they're called in postgres). Since it isn't a value but a part of `insert`'s syntax, it can't be bound to a placeholder, just like the table name cannot.

Comment: `DEFAULT` isn't just PostgreSQL. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9dca , http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9dca, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9dca . (MySQL, Oracle, and MS-SQL). BTW, that's the only time I've been able to simply run the *exact same code* on each. I'd call it a placeholder keyword.

Comment: @CraigRinger you learn something new every day, thanks! Did not expect to find it on other RDBMs. Not quite sure what it should be called, but IIUC, that fact doesn't change the essence of my answer - it's a syntax element, not a value, so it can't be bound.

Comment: JDBC has `PreparedStatement.setNull`, and `NULL` is only arguably a "value" too. I've been hoping there's a standard-but-obscure way to handle `DEFAULT`, but it's looking like "no".