# Inserting default value of integer into sql server through java

Tags: java, insert, sql-server-2012, prepared-statement

I am trying to use an if statement to check if a value equals `999999` and if it does the `DEFAULT` value needs to be inserted into the database.

```
       if (s.getYear() == 999999)
       {
           pstatement.setString(3, "DEFAULT");
       } 
       else 
       {
           pstatement.setInt(3, s.getYear());
       }
```

Pretty obviously, `sqlserver` refuses to insert a `String/Varchar` into an integer field.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'DEFAULT' to data type int.
```

Does anyone know how to insert the default value of that field?

Thanks

Comment: @BorisPavlović I believe the OP [means this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5352c/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage it form database side by using SQL,
**SQL**

```
ALTER TABLE `xxx` ALTER `supplier_id` SET DEFAULT NULL
```

Or

**Hibernate** If you are using hibernate you can set default value using `@Column`

```
@Column(name = “myColumn”, nullable = false, columnDefinition = “int default 100")
```

Answer (score 0):

When informing Sql Server to use the column's default during an insert via JDBC, AFAIK you will need to explicitly alter the DML statement so that the literal `DEFAULT` is used as the field's value, i.e. the PseudoCode

```
if (willUseDefault)
   sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, ColWithDefault) VALUES (?, ?, DEFAULT)";
else
   sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, ColWithDefault) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

And then you won't bind a value for parameter 3 of the prepared statement at all.

Another way to use the default value for a column is to omit the field off the insert column list entirely. This will similarly require you to adjust your DML statement.

```
if (willUseDefault)
   sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2) VALUES (?, ?)";
else
   sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable(Col1, Col2, ColWithDefault) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

This can get rather messy if multiple columns are to be conditionally defaulted in this manner.

Comment: Similar [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25781909/314291), seems no way to set `DEFAULT` via a parameter.