# Clojure and HugSQL; how to provide SQL keywords?

Tags: sql, jdbc, clojure

I have this query defined using HugSQL:

```
-- :name ins! :! :n
INSERT INTO table (col0, col1, col2) VALUES :tuple*:values;
```

How can I send a SQL keyword to this query from Clojure? In particular how could I do something like,

```
(ins! db {:values [[val0 val1 :DEFAULT] [val2 val3 val4]]})
```

such that the query becomes

```
INSERT INTO table (col0, col1, col2) VALUES (val0, val1, DEFAULT), (val2, val3, val4)
```

That is, how to use the SQL keyword DEFAULT from Clojure?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm using clojure.java.jdbc and postgresql.

Comment: You could try http://www.hugsql.org/#param-sql

Comment: Thanks, how would I combine that with the :tuple*:values above for inserting multiple rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the tuple list parameter type (:tuple*) is a value-based parameter type that defers to the underlying jdbc library for parameter replacement, you can't use it to insert raw/keyword sql.  This is actually noted here about JDBC's lack of support for this: [Sending the DEFAULT placeholder via JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779623/sending-the-default-placeholder-via-jdbc).

However, you can use HugSQL's [Clojure Expressions](http://www.hugsql.org/#using-expressions) to take the :values tuple list and re-write the query to treat Clojure keywords as SQL keywords, and all other values as SQL value parameters.  Below, we're using HugSQL's [Deep Get Param Name](http://www.hugsql.org/#deep-get-param-name) feature to reference the value parameters for the given indexes within the tuples.

```
-- :name insert-with-default :<!
/* :require [clojure.string :as string] */
insert into test (c1, c2, c3)
values
/*~ 
(string/join ","
  (map-indexed
    (fn [tuple-index tuple]
      (str 
        "(" 
        (string/join ","
          (map-indexed
            (fn [value-index value]
              (if (keyword? value)
                (name value)
                (str 
                  ":v:values." 
                  tuple-index "." 
                  value-index))) 
            tuple))
        ")"))
     (:values params)))
~*/
returning *
```

Resulting in (assuming 5 is the default value for c3):

```
(insert-with-default-sqlvec {:values [[1 2 :default]
                                      [3 4 :default]]})

;=> ["insert into test (c1, c2, c3)\n
      values  (?,?,default),(?,?,default) returning *" 1 2 3 4]

(insert-with-default db {:values [[1 2 :default]
                                  [3 4 :default]]})

;=> ({:c1 1, :c2 2, :c3 5} {:c1 3, :c2 4, :c3 5})
```

Comment: The next step in using/reusing this might be to create a [snippet](http://www.hugsql.org/#using-snippets) with just this expression in it, then use the snippet parameter type in your queries.