# Is passing an explicit null value to an identity column not allowed in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.10 with the 42.2.16 JDBC driver in a Java app.

When inserting null into the identity column I get a not-null violation.  That seems odd to me.  I explicitly set the mycol value to null since in some unrelated cases I need to specify a specific value which is guaranteed never to exceed the current max value of the column.

Does PostgreSQL really not allow me to use a prepared statement where the identity column value is null?  I would have expected the database just to autogenerate the value as desired.

Error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "mycol" violates not-null constraint
```

Column definition:

```
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                   
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 mycol    | bigint                      |           | not null | generated by default as identity
```

Comment: It is not allowed in any SQL based DBMS. Use `default` keyword instead of `null` if you want to specify this column in your `insert/update`

Comment: "*When inserting null into the identity column I get a not-null violation*" - this has nothing to do with the column being an identity column. If you try to store a NULL value into a column defined as NOT NULL this is correctly rejected by the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword here is `DEFAULT`: PostgreSQL will supply the generated value only if you don't, and even NULL is a value.

So you have two choices:

- omit the column in the column list:

  ```
  INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2, /* all except "mycol" */) VALUES (...);
  ```
- use `DEFAULT` for the value:

  ```
  INSERT INTO tab (mycol, ...) VALUES (DEFAULT, ...);
  ```

You'd get a better error message if you use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`:

```
ERROR:  cannot insert into column "mycol"
DETAIL:  Column "mycol" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
HINT:  Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

To get what you seem to want, you'd need a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION id() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   NEW.mycol := nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tab', 'mycol')::regclass);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER id BEFORE INSERT ON tab
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE id();
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the answer.  The answer of another question clarified that DEFAULT isn't an option with jdbc. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25781909/1824669  I'll just use two different insert statement and live with that.